# How to fill an asp DropDownCheckBoxes with a Dataset containing several Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset, dropdownchecklist

I have a '`DataSet` named DS1' filled with several '`datatable`' I want to load this DataSet to a `asp:DropDownCheckBoxes`

this is what I am doing, but it only loads the `asp:DropDownCheckBoxes` with the last table data

How can I write this?

```
this.MyDropDownCheckBoxes.DataSource = DS1;
this.MyDropDownCheckBoxes.DataTextField = "XXXX";
this.MyDropDownCheckBoxes.DataBind();
```

Thanks

Comment: the tables do not have names. it is filled with datatables

Comment: You can use an index. Or are you saying you want each of the tables in the dropdown?

Comment: Can you merge your datatables into a new one? And then use that one as your datasource.